# How to Display Sharepoint site name in a web part using below code?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Projects I am working on, I am trying to display Sharepoint site name in a web part using JS Snippet dynamically but I can't get it to work, can someone please help me correct the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("retrieveWebSite");

function retrieveWebSite() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
   this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
   clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title());
    var title = this.oWebsite.get_title();
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
      '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
} 

</script>
<div id ="title"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I was able to figure out an answer for the code.I had to change siteserverrelativeurl to webabsoluteurl and that read the current subsite. Hope this helps someone.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWebSite, "sp.js");
});
function retrieveWebSite() {
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
   this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
   clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
   //alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title());
    var title = this.oWebsite.get_title();
//alert(title);
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
      '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
} 

</script>
</head>
<div id ="title"></div>
<style>
#title{
    font-size:25px;
    text-color:#2b512e;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}
</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your script is executing before the default SharePoint JSOM libraries are loaded.  I added these script tags just under your jquery script tags and it started working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead of the _spBodyOnLoad function:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWebSite, "sp.js");
```

Your code looks good.  I agree with [@Robin](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/14556/robin), I think it i sa synchronicity problem.

Comment: Hi LazoDev, thanks. I made the change exactly as you mentioned and it satrted working about half an hour ago but the Problem is , it prints the root site name, not the current subsite name that the web part is displayed.  For example if the context is: http:// contoso.sharepoint.com/asset(subsite)/Plaza Junction(subsite),. then it displays contoso instead it should display Plaza junction and should be dynamic in nature. Is this doable?

Comment: Use get_current instead of what you have. 

Change new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl) to new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but still it returns Contoso and I don't understand why.

Comment: Hi LazoDev, would you be able to help me how to get the current library name using JSOM, thanks in advance.